# Pass in Form Values to Salesforce Community Create Record Page

Tags: community, custom-object, urlhacking

I'm trying to prepopulate some values on a Salesforce Community create record page based on a URL with URL params that is clicked.

**Use Case:**

User clicks: `https://mySandbox-request.cs24.force.com/s/createrecord/New_Request?Custom_Field__c=test`

Loads community page to create New Request custom objects with Custom_Field__c prepopulated with 'test'.

Is this possible?

I found the following Medium article, but I'm not following the authors user of {} in URL params: https://medium.com/@nialljpmurphy/using-url-parameters-with-your-salesforce-community-911e737fa47e

Comment: in the future this _should_ be possible - in regular salesforce... communities will hopefully follow 2-3 releases later. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the standard data entry modal window you get when you click the New button, you cannot prepopulate these fields by URL, either in Lightning Experience or Lightning Community.

The article is referring to Lightning components on the page that have modifiable  properties (i.e. the properties section for the component in the community Builder), or custom-built components that can pull parameters from the URL.